# How can I resolve $routeParameters with ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

I tried three different methods to direct a user to a new url:

1:

```
<a href="/customers/{{customer_id}}/info">
```

2:

```
<div ng-click="setRoute('/customers/{{customer_id}}/info')"></div>
```

3:

```
<div ng-click="go('/customers/{{customer_id}}/info')"></div>
```

where `{{customer_id}}` is a parameter and the angular functions are as follows:

```
$scope.setRoute = function(route){
    $location.path(route);
};

$scope.go = function ( hash ) {
    $location.hash( hash );
};
```

The problem is that only the first method works (`<a>`) when using a parameter. Unfortunately I can't use method 1 when I need to have a table row as a link. In that case it would be desirable to use methods 2 or 3. When I inspect the code I can see that my parameter is there (e.g., `/customers/123/info`), but for some reason this parameter is only being recognized if I use method 1. Can anyone help me figure this out? Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
<div ng-click="setRoute('/customers/'+customer_id+'/info')"></div>

<div ng-click="go('/customers/'+customer_id+'/info')"></div>
```

Plunkr proof for OP: http://plnkr.co/edit/tId8yZahYaGvQJ8FuIHT?p=preview

Comment: How can this work? Now the parameter ``customer_id`` just says "customer_id" instead of the actual customer id (e.g., "123").

Comment: Then you didn't use it like my example. It would be impossible for the function to be passed "/customers/customer_id/info" because customer_id is a variable. If the variable didn't exist you would get a variable undefined error. I tried this in a plunkr and it works.

Comment: I'm still not sure why it is that when I hard code ``customer_id`` into the url (e.g., /customers/123/info), then any of the above methods works (1, 2, or 3), but if I dynamically insert ``customer_id`` (using ``{{customer_id}}``) then it does NOT work. This is even though when I inspect the html I do see that ``{{customer_id}}`` has been replaced with an actual value (like "123").

Comment: `{{}}` is designed for displaying items on the page, not for passing as variables. You are in JavaScript when you are inside `ng-click`.

Comment: Okay. It's still weird to me that it won't work since I can see that {{customer_id}} has been replaced with an actual value. Either way, I tried this and it works: ``<tr ng-model="customer_id" ng-click="setRoute('/customer/'+customer_id+'/info')">``. Thanks for steering me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm having the same issue... angular 1.2.14, except my situation will work with options 2 and 3 from above if the variable is set in the controller at controller creation time.  In my case the scope variable is the result of a promise from an HTTP call, because of this I think the promise completion allows the HTML to look correct where as the ng-click compilation was bound to an empty variable.